# Operation amplifier concept problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

I'm new to op amps and I'm trying to grasp the concepts. Starting with a simple op amp buffer, with the output connected to the inverted input. One rule states that the op amp tries to keep the inputs at the same voltage, but before any voltage is applied, the inverted input would be at 0V if the voltage was sufficient enough wouldn't the output voltage be equal to v+ due to saturation? And if this was true, why wouldn't the inverted input equal this also? I'm trying to figure out where my understanding is wrong.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you've made your problems clear enough. What do you mean by "the inverted input would be at 0V if the voltage was sufficient enough wouldn't the output voltage be equal to v+ due to saturation"?

Comment: So before any voltage is given to the positive input, the inverted input would be at 0V. As soon as you introduce a voltage at the positive input, and let's say that the A factor makes it bigger than V+ so saturation would occur, wouldn't the output voltage be v+? Thus the input be V+?

Comment: If there is no signal at the positive input, then the voltage is not necessarily zero, it's called high impedance and the voltage is not defined in that case. If you ground the + input, then the input is zero volts and this circuit is not very interesting because the output is also zero.

As a general rule V+ = V- whenever you have output feeding back to the inverting terminal. In this case, we also have Vout = V-. The opamp will amplify the difference between V+ and V-. Since V+ - V- = 0, there will be no gain in this circuit and the output signal will be identical to the input signal.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, when I say V+ and V- I am referring to the input terminal voltages, not the supply voltages.

Comment: The assumption that is being made when you say that the feedback works to cancel the differences between the inputs when configured with negative feedback is that the amplifier is operating correctly which in turn means that the inputs are in the operational ranges specified and the outputs are within range.  If those conditions are not met then you can't make any assumptions.  Assuming saturation assumes a very specific configuration of transistors in the design which most people don't know - they just need to know how it works.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused. What if say the supply voltage is 5V and you input 1V then due to saturation, shouldn't the output be 5 at that instant?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear, from your question, what concept you're having a problem with.

According to the schematic, we can write the following equations

$$v_+ = v_{IN}$$

$$v_- = v_{OUT}$$

We also have, by definition of the op-amp with gain \$A\$

$$v_{OUT} = A(v_+ - v_-)$$

(note:  \$v_+\$ and \$v_-\$ are voltages at the non-inverting and inverting inputs respectively)

Combining these equations yields

$$v_{OUT} = A(v_{IN} - v_{OUT})$$

Solve for \$v_{OUT}\$

$$v_{OUT} = \frac{A}{1 + A}v_{IN}$$

Thus

$$v_+ - v_- = \frac{1}{1 + A}v_{IN} $$

For arbitrarily large \$A\$ (or taking the limit as \$A \rightarrow \infty\$), we have

$$v_{OUT} = v_{IN}$$

$$v_+ - v_- = 0$$

Now, is there anything in the above that you're having a problem with?

Comment: The math makes sense, but what's troubling me is how you can solve for v out when initially the voltage at the inverted input is undefined?? This is somewhat disconcerting and I feel I'm missing something blatantly obvious haha

Comment: @Paldan, evidently, the math *doesn't* make sense to you.  Where, in the math above, is there any suggestion that the inverting input is undefined at *any* time?  According to the math above, *at all times*, the inverting input voltage equals the output voltage.  And, according to the math above, the output voltage is proportional to the voltage across the op-amp inputs *at all times*.  Thus, *at all times*, the output voltage is proportional to the input voltage.  These equations are valid *at all times*.  When is there an undefined voltage?

Comment: I do understand the math, but my confusion came from being that I assumed that there must be a specified voltage at both input terminals so as to calculate a difference. (If that makes any sense to you)

Comment: @Paldan, there *is* a specified voltage at both input terminals *at all times*. The non-inverting input terminal has the specified voltage \$v_{IN}\$.  The inverting input terminal has the specified voltage \$\frac{A}{1+A}v_{IN}\$.  Now, if we add a *delay* through the op-amp, the equations become more complicated but, regardless, the input voltages are, at all times, defined.

Comment: What about the instant you apply a voltage? There can't be a voltage at the negative terminal.

Comment: @Paldan, why do you say that?  *Of course* there is a voltage at the negative terminal.  I honestly do not understand where you get this idea from.  The voltage at the negative terminal is precisely the voltage at the output terminal.

Comment: Yes I agree, but there must some delay before there is a voltage at the negative terminal?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I'm probably just over thinking it. It would be good to learn the internals for a better understanding. Thanks for your help any way! +1

Answer (score -1):

In more than 5 years, I will try to answer this question because I myself have been thinking a lot about it...

I think what @Paldan needed then was not math but an intuitive explanation for the transient process of this negative feedback system and in particular, the starting point after the input voltage is applied.

Maybe the main problem of understanding the operation of this most elementary op-amp circuit with negative feedback is that he/she thinks the input voltage can be applied instantly, like through some magic wand, to the non-inverting input... and that will find the inverting input unprepared to react (with some arbitrary voltage)?

But in practice, the input voltage is always set after some, albeit negligible, time ... primarily because of the stray capacitances. And since a unspoken convention is the op-amp is fast enough, its output voltage will track the input voltage. Well, if the transition is extremely steep, it may be a little late... but still it be able to "catch up".

It is also interesting to see what happens after turning on the power supply...